# How to reintroduce "no prompt to save" option in IDLE if file has never been saved

Tags: python, save, preferences, prompt, python-idle

Currently I am using the latest version of Python 2 on my laptop (2.7.12), along with IDLE version 2.7.12 and TK version 8.5.15, in case those are relevant.

On my school computers a slightly older version of IDLE is being used (version 2.7a0) which has, in the "general" tab of the IDLE preferences (under Options, Configure IDLE...), particular preferences that I no longer see in the latest version of IDLE that I installed on my laptop.

In particular, for the subsection "Run (F5) Preferences", it provides two options after the heading "If file has never been saved"; one "Prompt to Save" and the other "No Prompt".

I can't find this option under my more modern IDLE environment. I was hoping that one of you people might know whether there was some way to alter the modern version of IDLE or Python to reintroduce this feature? (For example, could I just open up some kind of source document for Python and make the modification myself?).

I just find it frustrating sometimes, because I often want to just create a new file with some very simple code to test whether my understanding of Python is correct with respect to particular concepts (i.e. how imaginary numbers work in arrays) without running my entire program which is often significantly more complex and will take a lot longer to test (and commenting everything out is extremely tedious the longer your code is). Having to open up a new file, enter my code, save it on my desktop, is kind of time consuming.

And believe it or not sometimes I will have multiple windows testing different concepts, because I want to continue testing Python in multiple ways without erasing the work I had previously done in other tests, which are ongoing.

Also in case it is relevant, the school computers are using Python version 2.7.12 and TK version 8.5 (I still need to figure out what TK means).

I understand that I could probably just roll back the version of IDLE to this earlier form (I'm assuming this would work anyway) - but I am also concerned that I may lose some key features that modern versions have, or that I will reintroduce some bugs that have previously been dealt with.

~Thanks for any help~

Unununium

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I am puzzled by this report.  The Autosave Preferences section is still present.  idlelib.configDialog.py, class ConfigDialog, method CreatePageGeneral has (should have) this code at lines 384 and 396.

```
    frameSave = LabelFrame(frame, borderwidth=2, relief=GROOVE,
                           text=' Autosave Preferences ')
    ...
    #frameSave
    labelRunSaveTitle = Label(frameSave, text='At Start of Run (F5)  ')
    radioSaveAsk = Radiobutton(
            frameSave, variable=self.autoSave, value=0,
            command=self.SetKeysType, text="Prompt to Save")
    radioSaveAuto = Radiobutton(
            frameSave, variable=self.autoSave, value=1,
            command=self.SetKeysType, text='No Prompt')
```

Except for adding spaces in 2014 to conform to PEP 8, this code is unchanged since 2003.  It is preceeded by Startup Preferences and Succeeded by Initial Window size.  I used hg annotate to look at how the file was in 2.6 and early 2.7.

It is possible that the repository record incomplete or that something was tried in an alpha0 release and removed because it did not work right (and both commit and revert erased).  If you find different code, you could paste the snipped and the part of the startup header that looks line "Python 2.7.12 (v2.7.12:d33e0cf91556, Jun 27 2016, 15:24:40)" into your question.

AFAIK, IDLE has always required new files to be saved to disk with a name as otherwise it would not be possible to create proper tracebacks.  Issue [19042](https://bugs.python.org/issue19042)on the tracker is a proposal to run 'Untitled' windows without given a name by having IDLE pick a name and path.  Or perhaps save in a user-configured directory.

The alpha-0 release of 2.7 would be the buggiest possible.  It should have been replaced.

OT: Tk is the GUI toolkit for [Tcl](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tcl).  Tkinter is Python's inter-face to tk.

Comment: I found the code you mentioned in configdialog.py - however it doesn't offer the 'radiobuttons' for "if file has never been saved". Then I went to 19042 on the tracker - and was shocked to discover you are the author of that very post asking for the same thing I am! That's really cool. I guess what I am asking for is precisely that modification to the autosave preferences you wanted - i.e. adding in a third option where the user is never prompted to save. And as you pointed out the unsaved new windows could be secretly saved to .idlerc/untitled.py. I will try to implement your suggestion

Comment: It would help a bit if you posted a supporting comment on the issue.

Comment: Well I will certainly try to support your bid to adopt change 19042 on the tracker. I just need to figure out how to do that exactly (I'm kind of new to a lot of this). If you meant supporting comment with respect to my original question, I guess I don't have that much to add except that I hope I can somehow figure stuff out and modify python's core .py code. What I will *try* to do is look at my school computers and see if I can copy and paste the relevant code which is different. It might be possible...